# Unable to post to a host via https protocol in local Google App Engine sandbox

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, mandrill

I want to use the mandril python lib (https://bitbucket.org/mailchimp/mandrill-api-python) to communicate with Mandrill's API server (https://mandrillapp.com/)

I have added the relevant source codes to my project. I have also enabled library `ssl` in `app.yaml`

However I encountered a 'Permission denied' exception when I tried to use one of a Mandrill API.

Here is the stack trace

```
  File "lib/mandrill/mandrill.py", line 1498, in send_template
    return self.master.call('messages/send-template', _params)
  File "lib/mandrill/mandrill.py", line 159, in call
    r = self.session.post('%s%s.json' % (ROOT, url), data=params, headers={'content-type': 'application/json', 'user-agent': 'Mandrill-Python/1.0.57'})
  File "lib/requests/sessions.py", line 504, in post
    return self.request('POST', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "lib/requests/sessions.py", line 461, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "lib/requests/sessions.py", line 573, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "lib/requests/adapters.py", line 415, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(13, 'Permission denied'))
```

I have double-checked the API key issue using Mandrill command line utility and I am sure it is not the source of the problem.

If I printed out the os.environ, I can see this  key value pair: `'HTTPS': 'off'`

Does this environment variable has anything to do with this issue? What caused the 'Permission denied' problem?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Mandrill, but maybe it wants you to have a good SSL certificate to initiate HTTPS connections to it?

Comment: @AlexMartelli Hi, I always feel it is a great honour to have your response to my question. So a big thank-you and happy new year! I looked in the SSL cert direction but it is not the cause. I think I've found a solution and I will post an answer shortly!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the `requests` library does not play well with a local instance of GAE. The problem is similar to [this issue](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Python-SDK/issues/66).

Here I quote katzlbt's root cause analysis from the aforementioned ticket:

> It is known that the authors of "requests" do not support google
>   appengine and will not do so in future. requests works now on the live
>   environment (only for billing enabled appengine apps), but not on the
>   local SDK, which makes implementing a solution based on your library a
>   nightmare on appengine, and basically untestable offline. Only
>   uploading to the live server works.

Using a similar technique, this is my monkey-patching code:

```
import json
import time
import requests

class _Response(object):
    def __init__(self, dict):
        self.__dict__ = dict

def _monkeypatched_mandrill_call(self, url, params=None):
    from google.appengine.api import urlfetch
    from mandrill.mandrill import ROOT

    if params is None: params = {}
    params['key'] = self.apikey
    params = json.dumps(params)
    self.log('POST to %s%s.json: %s' % (ROOT, url, params))
    start = time.time()

    headers = {'content-type': 'application/json', 'user-agent': 'Mandrill-Python/1.0.57'}
    uf_response = urlfetch.fetch('%s%s.json' % (ROOT, url), method='post', payload=params, headers=headers)
    remote_addr = (None, None)

    # construct a request-like response
    r = _Response({
        'status_code' : uf_response.status_code,
        'reason' : None,
        'text' : uf_response.content,
        'headers' : uf_response.headers,
    })

    response_body = r.text
    complete_time = time.time() - start
    self.log('Received %s in %.2fms: %s' % (r.status_code, complete_time * 1000, r.text))
    self.last_request = {'url': url, 'request_body': params, 'response_body': r.text, 'remote_addr': remote_addr, 'response': r, 'time': complete_time}

    result = json.loads(response_body)

    if r.status_code != requests.codes.ok:
        raise self.cast_error(result)
    return result

def monkey_patch_gae():
    ''' Call this function to patch mandrill when running a local GAE instance '''
    from mandrill import mandrill
    mandrill.Mandrill.call = _monkeypatched_mandrill_call
```

This patch works for `mandril-api-python` of version 7d041d5